# Pandas use index in new column calculation

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A', 'B', 'C'}, columns = ['Letter'])
```

Indexes are set automatically as [0,1,2]

Then I want to add a new column that would extract the index numeric value from the length of the dataframe:

```
df['Calc'] = len(df) - df.index
```

It gives me an error as:
ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (3)

However, if I add indexes myself when creating the dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A', 'B', 'C'}, columns = ['Letter'], index = [0,1,2])
df['Calc'] = len(df) - df.index
```

It works well and adds new column:

|  | Letter | Calc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 3 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 2 | C | 1 |

I m working with much bigger datasets and with more complicated calculations, but I cant understand the logic behind this behavior. In my another example, pandas would add the new column to the DataFrame with no error, but as soon as I reset_index(), it does not work.

Could you please explain the behaviour?

Comment: In the first case `df.index` is a `RangeIndex`, which is dynamic; in the second version it's an `Index`, which is fixed. You can see the difference if you do `print(df.index)`

Comment: Beside the point, but why are you using a set for the data? Sets are not ordered. Did you mean to use a list and just put the wrong brackets? (i.e. `['A', 'B', 'C']`)

Comment: If you look at the result of `len(df) - df.index`, you can see the problem: `RangeIndex(start=3, stop=0, step=1)`. A descending range needs to have a negative `step`, otherwise it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.values` to your index and this will convert your RangeIndex into a list of values.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=['Letter'])
df['Calc'] = len(df) - df.index.values
```

```
  Letter  Calc
0      A     3
1      B     2
2      C     1
```